# Win8 scroll bar at bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-8

Hey guys im developing a win8 application and cant find a solution to this, how do i get the horizontal scroller at the bottom of the page in win8

btw im using

```
#container{display:-ms-grid;}

.col1{-ms-grid-column:1;}
.col2{-ms-grid-column:2;}
.col3{-ms-grid-column:3;}
```

Anyone have a solution, and maybe a reason why the scroller follows the content height?? and not the window height.

Comment: Are you using the `ListView data-win-control`?

Comment: yeah i made like container for all my scripts and then the data-win-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution i had to set all my out divs to 100% of height, and then the section tag that wrap each of my pages to 88% height and then the header to 12%.

last but not least set my section tag to overflow-x:scroll;

short version of the code:

```
body{height:100%;}
header{height:12%;}
section{
  height:88%;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  display:block;
}
#contenthost{height:100%;}
.pagediv{height:100%;}
```

and that solved my problem

Best regards
SP